# iphone alarm at selected time

Tags: iphone, timer, alarm

I am having trouble creating alarm app.
all I have is Datepicker, label, button.

```
@interface app6ViewController : UIViewController {
 UILabel *dateLabel;
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    NSDate *alarm;
}

-(IBAction)getSelection;

    -(IBAction)checkAlarm;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;


@end
```

and in .m file

```
    -(void)getSelection
{

 //from date picker good part

    NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc]
                           initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];

    NSDate *pickerDate = [datePicker date];
    NSString *selectionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [pickerDate descriptionWithLocale:usLocale]];
    dateLabel.text = selectionString;

    [selectionString release];


    alarm = pickerDate;

    //[mylabel setText:(@"text")]; //this string works
    NSTimer *checkAlarm = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(checkAlarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)checkAlarm:(NSTimer *)t{
    if ([NSDate date] == alarm){
        // Alarm reached
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
        message:@"Alarm"
        delegate:nil 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]  ;   
        [t invalidate]; 
    }
}
```

but I it doesnt triggers alarm :( I cant figure out why.

Comment: First of all check that your checkAlarm function calls or not or if it calls then i think set delegate:self instead of delegate:nil

Answer (score 0):

check with breakpoint whether your alarm method is called ??
try like this ...something

```
-(void)getSelection
{

 //from date picker good part

    NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc]
                           initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];

    NSDate *pickerDate = [datePicker date];
    NSString *selectionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [pickerDate descriptionWithLocale:usLocale]];
    dateLabel.text = selectionString;

    [selectionString release];


    alarm = pickerDate;

    //[mylabel setText:(@"text")]; //this string works

    NSTimer *checkAlarm =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkAlarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:no]; 
}

-(void)checkAlarm{
    if ([NSDate date] == alarm){
        // Alarm reached
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
        message:@"Alarm"
        delegate:nil 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]  ;   

    }
```

Comment: displays warning: Usused variable 'checkAlarm'